# Finding the x coordinate of A

Tags: calculus, geometry

The curve C has this equation:

$2x^{2}y+2x+4y-\cos(\pi y) = 17$

The point $\mathbf{P}$ with coordinates $(3, \frac{1}{2})$ lies on C.

The normal C at P meets the x-axis at the point A.

a. Find the x coordinate of A, giving your answer in the form $\frac{a\pi + b}{c\pi + d}$

Where do I begin? I thought of replacing the X and Y values with the coordinates, however, that's not the result I'm expecting.

Comment: Find the slope of the tangent at point $P$ and then the slope perpendicular to it. That gives you equation of line as it passes through $P$ and finally its intersection with $y=0$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2x^{2}y+2x+4y-\cos(\pi y) = 17 \implies 4xy+2x^2y'+2+4y'+\pi y' \sin(\pi y)=0$$
$$ y'(x,y)=\frac{(-4xy-2)}{2x^2+4+\pi \sin \pi y} \implies y'(3,1/2)=\frac{-8}{22+\pi},m_N=\frac{22+\pi}{8}.$$ $m_N$ is the slope of the required normal whose equation is
$$y-1/2=\frac{22+\pi}{8}(x-3).$$ When $y=0$, the value of $x$ is
$$x=\frac{3\pi+62}{\pi+22}\implies a=3,b=62,c=1,d=22.$$

Comment: How did you get $\pi$ on the numerator? shouldn't it be: $\frac{8}{22+\pi}$?

Comment: Furthermore, I'm not sure how you derived 124? Am I missing something here, whenever I re-arrange the equation, I end with 132?

Comment: @jj_ellison I am extremely sorry my solution was incorrect, I have revised it now. Please see.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you need the slope of the curve at the given point, and for this you can (or have ) to differentiate implicitly:

$$2x^{2}y+2x+4y-cos(\pi y) = 17\implies4xy+2x^2y'+2+4y'+\pi\sin\pi y\,y'=0\implies$$

$$(2x^2+4+\pi\sin\pi y)y'=-4xy-2\implies y'=-\frac{4xy+2}{2x^2+4+\pi\sin\pi y}$$

and now imput the coordinates of $\;P\;$ in the above and you have the slope of the tangent to the curve at $\;P\;$ (or the slope of the curve at $\;P\;$, as we many time use to say in short), so now find the normal = the perpendicular to this tangent line...